# Compatibility between oracle 19c and .net (mvc)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle19c

The project works in

- .Net Framework MVC 4.6
- The Oracle Database updated to 19.0.48.0.0

My application work in a complex infrastructure and the update to .net core framework, it isn't good!

I was look for this solution 2 or 3 weeks, but all information involved update the application to .NET CORE. (**The Oracle Database updated to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version to 19.3.0**)

Error explorer "Oracle data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.48.0.0"

Error in application:

```
 public static Context Create(string tenantSchema, DbConnection connection, bool starTablesContext = true)
        {
            var compiledModel = modelCache.GetOrAdd(
                Tuple.Create(connection.ConnectionString, tenantSchema),
                t =>
                {
                    var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
                    //builder.Conventions.Remove<ColumnTypeCasingConvention>();
                    builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                    builder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
                    if (starTablesContext) StartTables(builder, tenantSchema);
                     //Error in this line 
                    var model = builder.Build(connection);

                    return model.Compile();
                });
            return new Context(connection, compiledModel, tenantSchema);
        }
```

Do someone know how to fix this without update it?

Is there another solution?

I'm afraid in update all application in this solution to .NET Core, hard work because MVC and .NET CORE require many changes to work,  and after this the issue doesn't be fix and to cause any others.

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. " (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Why don't you want to update to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 19.3? You can use it with the full .NET Framework. No need to switch to .NET Core. [The release notes for the version mention it is certified for .NET Framework 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/release_changes.html#GUID-71170E94-705B-4B27-9ABE-72D8BE954793)...

Comment: Did you use the correct driver? Did you use an up-to-date version? Did you use the .NET Old or .NET Core version> The latest version of [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/) is 3.21.3, not 19.3.

Comment: `the update to .net core framework` there's no such thing. .NET Framework is the old runtime that stopped at .NET Framework 4.8 and is in maintenance mode. .NET Core is the new, cross-platform runtime. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. The latest version is .NET 6 RC1 which, while not finalized, is supported in production. .NET Core was released 5 years ago so there are a *lot* of differences and breaking changes with .NET Old. Web development itself is *very* different. There are far bigger differences in Web API, Razor Pages and MVC than the Oracle ADO.NET driver

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is no such thing as .NET Core 5. There was .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.8. Now there is .NET 5. As long as we're being pedantic ;-P

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, thanks for to tips, I changed the question structure and removed the link to images. I don't found the requirement about .net framework to work in nowhere (Nuget packet [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/19.3.0)). I went in this page cited by you, but did access other releases 19c.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, i don't using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core. I am using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in .Net 4.6. Until 12c did work fine, but the upgrade to version 19c caused this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, 'update' maybe can be vague, but i did want to say refactoring my application for this new platform .Net CORE. Thanks by answer.

Comment: @HeitorMagaldi  `i don't using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` there's your problem. You're using the wrong package. You can't use a .NET Old package with .NET Core. They're two completely different runtimes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh, .NET 5 is very much .NET Core 5. The name change was just marketing. This isn't about being pedantic. It's about making people understand that they can't just migrate from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5, because it's a completely different runtime. Migrating from .NET Old 4.8 to .NET 5 takes as much work as migrating to .NET Core 3.1. On the other hand, upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to 5 requires only a number change in `csproj`

Comment: @HeitorMagaldi if you remain on .NET Framework, have you tried upgrading to the newest package?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, If there isn't other way, i will do. This project is very complex and there are any dependencies, relationship with other projects and libs, today work fine in 4.6, in the update to 4.8 don't it. But, if there isn't other way, it's way! Thank's !!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5.0 and beyond has some risks and should be done incrementally, if at all. It might make more sense to rewrite as .NET 5.0+ at a later point due to breaking API changes. We have most of our code running in .NET Framework 4.8 still and it is not cost effective to upgrade/port everything to .NET 5.0 at this time. There is a larger initiative to rewrite the our monolithic applications as microservices in .NET 5.0+.

One of the recent projects I worked on involved connecting to Oracle and leveraging EF Core 3.1. EF Core 3.1 is compatible with .NET Framework 4.8 because it targets .NET Standard 2.0. We are using version 3.x of the [Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/3.21.3) Nuget package which works with EF Core 3.1. Version 5.x of the package requires .NET Standard 2.1 which is incompatible with .NET Framework 4.8. Additionally, it would require EF Core 5.x or higher which also requires .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: Hi @Cameron Tinker ! Thanks by reply, refactoring and update framework is really challenger. I added the question to look to another way, other opinions and to found don't trivial resolution.
But, other hand, each reply to show up something new and certily will to help me in this challenge !